# php-How to fast convert or make image in imagemagic?

Tags: php

I use imagemagick with php.
I create code to convert/make image. But the process is very slow.
How to make this faster??

```
<?php
// Example 1
$pieces  = $_POST["name"]; 
echo shell_exec("convert -background lightblue  -fill blue  -font arial -pointsize 25 -size 480x320   caption:\"$pieces.\" z0.png");
?>
```

Comment: Careful... you're accepting **anything** posted to your script and executing it.  This is a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: ok but how to do it fast it takes too much time when it use for large image??so how to do it fast??

Answer (score 0):

Try using phmagick class available at

http://www.phmagick.org/development/php-development/do-some-imagemagick

it gives easy to use functions, gives faster result

Comment: what is this ?? you are promoting your blog here

Comment: it is a php class that helps to use imagemagick with php, so instead of shell commands you can use functions